# sharepoint list choice required field

Tags: 2007, list, choice-field

Using out-of-the-box SharePoint 2007, I want to create a required "choice" field that has values but no spaces/blanks as a valid option. I then want the entry form to show a blank as you select information on this field, and then validation to fail when no selection is made.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy, yet counter-intuitive to do.
Just set the default value to blank, even though there is no blank option in the values you are using. Pictured below.

[image]

Comment: You can just delete the default value - does not have to be a space.

Comment: yeah... you're right. I just figured that out.